# prepare xts entry in a table for hc_add_series_list

Tags: r, xts, r-highcharter

I am working with a tibble containing a column of xts as in the following example:

```
oneDf <- data.frame( name = "first", t = seq(now(),length=5,by = "days"), val = runif(5))
secDf <- data.frame( name = "sec",t = seq(now(),length=5,by = "days"), val = runif(5))

nested_data <- union(oneDf,secDf) %>% 
                  group_by(name) %>% 
                  nest() %>% 
                  mutate(data = map(data, ~.x %>% 
                  transmute(val, t) %>% 
                  column_to_rownames("t") %>% as.xts()))

> nested_data
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  data         
  <chr> <list>       
1 first <xts [5 × 1]>
2 sec   <xts [5 × 1]>
```

The aim is to use **hc_add_series_list** to show the xts all named by the name-col.
The preparation for hc_add_series (where the problem occurs) is as follows:

```
test <- nested_data %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        do( ds = list( data = list_parse2(data.frame(row.names(.$data),coredata(.$data))))) %>% 
        {map2(.$name,.$ds, function(x,y){append(list(name=x),y)})}
```

...generates an Error due to the date-frame generation, so that I cannot use, as intended

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(test)
```

How do I have to change the data.frame(...) to get this to work?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As I work with nested data, the following leads to an output:

```
    test <- nested_data  %>% 
  mutate(ds = map(data,function(x) { 
    timestamps <- time(x) %>% as.POSIXct() %>% as.numeric()
    values <- as.numeric(x)
    list( data = list_parse2(data.frame(timestamps,values))) })) %>% 
  {map2(.$name,.$ds, function(x,y){append(list(name=x),y)})}
```

... but still Highcharter shows the wrong time coordinate (points started at Jan 20(??) with a distance of some minutes...). timestamps <- index(x) leads to the same strange behavior...

edit:
solved, timestamps <- index(x) * 1000 did the job :-)